# Аргумент функции по умолчанию равен []

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть простой код:

```
def b(a=[]):
    print(a)
    a.append(1)


b()
b()
b()
```

Если запустить скрипт, то в консоль выведется `[]`, `[1]`, `[1, 1]`
Это происходит из-за того, что на объект `[]` ссылается имя `а`, а это имя не удаляется так как её замыкает функция `b`? Просто хочу понять как это работает, а не просто принимать это как данность

Comment: Просто, значение по умолчанию у параметра задается один раз -- при объявлении функции, поэтому при вызовах функции этот объект будет использован

Comment: Вы не поняли вопрос. Мой вопрос состоит в том, почему так происходит

Comment: Марк Лутц "Изучаем Python", глава 17 «Области видимости и вложенные функции» и раздел «Типичные ошибки при работе с функциями».

Comment: @СергейТерпеливый она не удаляется потому, что достижимому имени `b` присвоен объект функции, объект функции содержит атрибут `__defaults__`, атрибут `__defaults__` ссылается на кортеж, а кортеж содержит список для аргумента `a`. Пока существует функция, существуют её аргументы по умолчанию.

Comment: Именно потому и происходит, что аргумент по умолчанию _вычисляется_ при __определении__ функции а не при __вызове__. ведь в определении функции может быть и такое `def f(x = g())` и функция `g` будет вызвана только один раз, а не каждый раз. А `[]` можно считать вызовом `list()` без параметров.